# Scalar variable not declared

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
protected void DropDownList8_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    var updateCmd = "UPDATE [CarTab] SET Rent= 1 WHERE ([Model] = @Model)";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateCmd, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Error : Must declare scalar variable for @Model.
What should I remove/add there? Can't figure it out. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", value);
```

You complete code

```
protected void DropDownList8_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    var updateCmd = "UPDATE [CarTab] SET Rent= 1 WHERE ([Model] = @Model)";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        using(var command = new SqlCommand(updateCmd, connection))
        {
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", value); //Replace with your value

          command.Connection.Open();
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the parameter `@Model`, like:

```
    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Model", SqlDbType.SomeType);
    updateCmd.Parameters["@Model"].Value = something;
```